# Variable's value changes for no reason

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple tiktakto game with html, css, js. I am making a gamemode where you can square up against the computer. This code is supposed to check if a column should be blocked by the bot:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {   
        for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            console.log("j = ", j)
             
            S += board[j][i];
        }  // <-- inside for loop j only goes from 0 to 2

        if(S === 2) // <-- inside of this if statemnt j is 3
        {   
            console.log("j = ", j) 
            if(prevent(i, j, "column")) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
        S = 0;
    }
```

However somewhere after for loop the value of j randomly goes from 2 to 3 before the prevent() function can be executed, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop:

```js
for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
  console.log("j = ", j)

  S += board[j][i];
}
```

Is equivalent to this while loop:

```js
j = 0
while (j <= 2) {
  console.log("j = ", j)

  S += board[j][i];

  j++
}
```

So if `j <= 2` is `true` the body loop body is executed and also the `j++`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop will only stop once the condition evaluates to false. Here, the first time `j <= 2` is `false` is when `j` has been incremented to `3`.